# How could a comments plugin be securely loaded from domains people are already logged into?

Tags: web-application, authentication, appsec, http, third-party

The fundamental idea is to load a blog comments plugin (like Disqus) from a domain someone is already logged into to save users time and increase engagement.

I like the facebook comments plugin because people are usually logged into facebook, but not everyone is keen on having their comments go through facebook and be locked into their 'walled garden'.

Organizationally and technically, how could a generic comments page be loaded from a domain someone is already logged into (like FB and Google) in a secure manner?

Comment: meta: my first post on security stack exchange, does it belong here? It has strong UX motivations

Answer (score 1):

Since the frontend code for a comments plugin is already publicly viewable, it only makes sense for it be fully open source on github. Big sites would then have to review and pull the latest changes and host them on their domains.

Technically:
By default, a blog could be set to load the comments iframe from a big site like facebook or google. If the person was not logged into that domain, instead of being prompted to login, they would be redirected to google, and so on and so forth until a domain just isn't being found. Only then would a user be asked to login with one of the services.

Also, since this would be pretty magical/mystical to a user it would be important to show "Logged in through facebook.com" with the option to login through a different domain (or maybe connect/merge accounts)